# How do I make input field un-editable after user has entered some value

Tags: html, jquery

I have an input field where user will enter a phone number and next click a button which will generate an OTP.
I have tried Jquery disable method but the issue is when I make it disable the number in Input field doesnot get saved in the database...

Comment: Can you add more details on your questions or some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, disabled means that the field is not included in form submission, so what you want instead is readOnly, so :

```
 $('#number').prop('readOnly', true);
```

Note that readOnly is case-sensitive.